# Load static assets with vue-cli 3.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a vue-cli 3 project setup with the following directory structure:

[image]

All static assets are loaded in the **public directory** and are compiled and built successfully on *localhost*.

As seen in the image below, *guyana-live-logo.png*, *slide-1.jpg* and *970x250-ad.png* are all loaded successfully, however, only the logo and the ad image appears in the browser.

[image]

### What I've tried

1. **Changing the way the image is referenced.**

*Original - which works for almost all other images*

```
<img src="/img/slide-1.jpg"/>
```

*Test 0 - this loaded the image with a hash appended (slide-1.1b0ahsa.jpg) but it still did not appear in the browser*

```
<img src="../../../public/img/slides/slide-1.jpg">
```

*Test 1 - using v-bind*

```
<img :src="'/img/slide-1.jpg'"/>
```

2. **Moving the image inside the src directory and the component sub-directory** both of which proved futile.
3. **Updating vue-loader**
4. **Building for production and serving only the /dist folder**

### Key notes

- The console or my bug tracking software produces no error.
- Image format doesn't seem to be the problem, some `.png` loads while others don't, the same is true for `.jpg`.
- Some JavaScript files are affected. JS files are being called like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= BASE_URL %>js/script.js"></script>` in **public/index.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images will need to be in the same directory or a child directory of the file in which you're trying to access them (i.e. in the `Components` directory).

Can you also try to access the image via its URL `<img src="http://localhost:8080/img/guyana-live-logo.png" />`?

This should work, but you may not want to use it this way.

Another possibility you might be able to use is doing this:

```
<script>
import image from './img/slide-1.jpg'
...
```

Then in Vue `data`:

```
  data() {
    return {
      img: image,
    };

  },
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<img :src="image"/>
```

This solves issues when trying to access images when building with Parcel Bundler

Comment: @orangeMnint thanks for taking the time to respond. I appreciated it as it helped me figure out the true cause of the debacle. Nothing was wrong with the parcel loader or how I called the image but the underlying cause was a CSS class added to hide the image, `git blame` will tell me who was responsible for this nonsense! I figured it out by visiting the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/) and comparing the DOM elements.

Comment: Additionally, the second option of importing the image in the script will cause Vue to through an error since it's not a module. Accessing the image through it's URL is  more feasible but only if done dynamically so as to avoid hardcoding.

We may have this `img: '${window.location.href}img/slide-1.jpg',` in the data object and called like this `:src="img"` in the html.

Comment: @carlhandy glad you got it figured out! If my answer helped you solve your problem, could you select it as the answer? thanks!